# Enabling AR session in unity makes android crash

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, ar-foundation

Im currently working with a new project with unity AR.
I downloaded related packages, set NDK, SDK. also removed vulkan in graphic apis of playersetting and set target api level to 33 and minum api to android 7.0.
I also set scripting backgend from mono to IL2CPP and check armv7, arm 64.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6sVn.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsJRr.png)

these photos are screenshots of my project hierachy. As you can see, this is really simple project. Few days ago, everything worked well in android. but suddenly from yesterday, unity AR doesnt work at all in my phone(Samsung galaxy fold 3, api level 33). As soon as i openend the app, it crashed and everything didnt work at all

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEhzO.png)

this is the screenshot of the project when I started in my phone. it just stops as soon as I started and doesnt work at all.

And i figured out that only if AR Session script is enabled, than app crashs in android(play in unity editor is fine).
As i said above, I checked arm 64 and set graphics api and target api, scripting backend. i even tried to uncheck multhread Rendering.  But all of these didnt work so far.... And i checked ARCore in XR plugin...

I keep searching about this, but most of informations are about arm64 and etc that i tried before. please help me.

Comment: Same issue here. But happens only on samsung's phone. On the pixel phone it still work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You should attach your samsung-device with android logcat, to check the main issue causing error
For Android logcat ,
go to unity package manager and search for logcat in Unity registry